# How to concatenate items In ArrayList and set to Spinner Android

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to android development.

I want to concatenate (Add a string to each item in an array list) and set it to my spinner

I have 2 arrays:

Array 1 = `{ Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4 }`

Array 2 = `{ A, B, C, D }`

So I am setting only **Array1** in spinner like this:

```
ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.spn_item_selected, Array1)
```

Right now, this is what is displayed in the spinner:

**Item1**

**Item2**

**Item3**

**Item4**

How do I add items in array 2 to the items in array 1 so I can display something like this in the spinner

**Item1, A**

**Item2, B**

**Item3, C**

**Item4, D**

For a string I could do this:

```
 val a = "Hello"
 val b = "Baeldung"
 val c = a + " " + b
 //result
 Hello Baeldung
```

But this is an array all gotten from a backend

Sorry if this may be simple, I have searched but didnt find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [zip](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-transformations.html#zip) with transform function to combine both arrays to one:

```
val l1 = listOf("item1", "item2", "item3")
val l2 = listOf("a", "b", "c")


val res = l1.zip(l2) { a: String, b: String -> "$a,$b" }

//[item1,a, item2,b, item3,c]
```